# Node.js Accessing parent modules

Tags: node.js

I am working on a CMS system for Node.js, I have a quick question for those Node.js Pro's

I am creating modules and requiring modules within those modules, but if I have already included this module in the parent module, can I access those required modules?

For Example:

```
main.js
    var fs = require('fs');
    var sc = require('second.js');


second.js
    var fs = require('fs'); // Is there any way to use the parent modules fs object?
```

It just seems I am including the same modules in some of my sub modules and rather not do that if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, since Node caches modules when they're first included (i.e. the side-effects of requiring a module won't be executed a second time). You can force this cache to be cleared (and thus re-execute said side-effects) by tampering with `require.cache`.

Comment: I did read that, but just seems redundant. But if there is no disadvantages, then I will just keep re-including them.

Comment: I think that is the way to go with a modular system as each module has a clear "input" (requires and function parameters) and an "output" (exports).

Answer (score 12):

In case you came here looking for a simple way to get the parent module from the current module, here's a way of doing that:

```
var parent = module.parent.exports;
```

The module object stores quite a bit of useful information, including a reference to the parent module that loaded it. You could also do it like so:

```
var parent = module.require( module.parent.id );
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that `module.parent` refers to the parent who *first* loaded the module, not the parent in that particular instance.